# Sum of positive arrays yields negative results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, integer

I try to sum together three positive arrays, however, the result yields an array that has negative values. How is this possible?

```
#Example of an image
img=np.array(([[[246, 240, 243],[240, 239, 239],
       [243, 242, 244]],[[ 241, 240, 240],
       [241, 243, 246],[ 239, 239, 239]],
       [[249, 249, 250],[  33,  33,  34],
       [249, 249, 249]],[[  33,  33,  33],
       [250, 250, 249],[  34,  34,  34]]]), dtype=np.uint8)

#Creating three positive arrays from image
#Image type converted to np.int16 as otherwise values remain between 0-255
R=abs((img[:,:,0].astype(np.int16)-255)**2)
G=abs((img[:,:,1].astype(np.int16)-255)**2)
B=abs((img[:,:,2].astype(np.int16)-255)**2)

print(R, G, B)
[[   81   225   144]
 [  196   196   256]
 [   36 16252    36]
 [16252    25 16695]] [[  225   256   169]
 [  225   144   256]
 [   36 16252    36]
 [16252    25 16695]] [[  144   256   121]
 [  225    81   256]
 [   25 16695    36]
 [16252    36 16695]]

#Adding three positive arrays together
R+G+B
array([[   450,    737,    434],
       [   646,    421,    768],
       [    97, -16337,    108],
       [-16780,     86, -15451]], dtype=int16)
```

I thought it had something to do with the abs() function I am applying, however, the results separately clearly show they are referenced correctly and positive?

Comment: It happens because of byte overflow. `16695` in binary is `0100 0001 0011 0111`. `16695 + 16695 + 16695 = 50085(unsigned)` in binary it's `1100 0011 1010 0101`. You're using `np.int16` whicc is signed type and signed bit is set

Comment: Ok...  that is not great. Is there a way to overcome it because in my case the result is problematic

Comment: Try to use `np.uint16` here `.astype(np.uint16)`

Comment: I tried that, the values are now at least positive, but still not correct! array([49284,    25, 48841], dtype=uint16)*3 yields array([16780,    75, 15451], dtype=uint16)

Comment: You need to use a dtype that's large enough to hold your maximum value. numpy doesn't use infinite-precision integers like ordinary Python `int` variables.

Comment: np.uint64? This seems to work fine for now! You could add it as an answer for me to accept